# Break out of CONTENT LOCK by someone else

Tags: locking

I have a famous site, lets call it `www.mywebsite.com`

Someone purposely booked a similar domain that has a misspellig in it; `www.mywebste.com` and put a content lock that forces people to fill up surveys in order to get thru to my site.

People are fooled to think this is the original site asking them do so.

Searched everywhere to try and find a script that breaks out of those content blockers but couldn't.
Only ones available are for breaking out of iframes.